# Gradle with multiple subproject running tests

Tags: gradle

Let's assume that I have such structure of a gradle project:

```
:app:api 
:app:domain 
:app:infra 
:app:libs:lib1 
:app:libs:lib2
```

`Infra` depends on `lib1` and `lib2`.

As far as I know, if you run task *test* for infra, gradle by default runs all *test* tasks for all the dependent projects, which are:
:app:libs:lib1
:app:libs:lib2

How can I disable this functionality? I want to run `gradlew app:infra:test`, I want to run tests just in infra and not to run tests in lib1 and lib2?

If I run `gradlew test`, then I want to run all the tests.